# Migrating data from 11G Linux to 19C on Windows

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I'm using datapump to move data from 11.2.0.4 on Linux to 19C on Windows. It seems to be working except for some objects in the system schemas. Is there any reason to bring these schemas across or can I simply exclude them?

Answer (score 2):

Always exclude them. They contain version and instance-specific metadata that should not be migrated. When performing this kind of migration (porting applications to new DB versions), only ever export/import your application schemas and user accounts. Never do a "full" export/import.

If you have already overwritten some data dictionary objects and experienced errors, you may need to validate the state of your dictionary (see here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/hcheck-sql-check-known-data-dictionary-problems) and consider a restore from backup to a point prior to your import.